# Can't access asp controls from static method, but when I remove static, ajax call won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a method called getPersonInfo and it's header looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static Hashtable getPersonInfo(int personID)
{
}
```

The problem I am having is that this method cannot access my asp.net controls. So of course I remove the "static" keyword. But then my ajax calls fail since it's not a static method any more. Any suggestions?

EDIT: After reading and searching for a bit, I've realized that it won't work. What I am asking is if there is another way of maybe getting the final result, as for now I'm unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Hint: AJAX methods must be `static` for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

AJAX methods do not run the page lifecycle, so the controls don't actually exist on the server.

Instead, you need to manipulate the page on the client.

Comment: how would I do that? could you maybe provide an example? or a suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery or pure javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the values of controls to the getPersonInfo method from client side. For ex: if its JQuery ajax call, additional parameters can be passed using "data" property. Ofcourse, again the getPersonInfo method signature needs to be modified accordingly.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'adduser.aspx/getPersonInfo',                        
data: { personID: $('txtPersonId').val() }, //pass additional parameters here
type: "POST",
success: function (template) {
alert('success'); },
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('error');
}
});
```